# How do I prevent an absolute position table header from overflowing horizontally?

Tags: css, html-table

I am trying to make a table with a "sticky" table header. I set the  position to absolute and it works, but now the header overflows horizontally past the table borders and even covers the scrollbar. How can I make an element absolute but still visually contained by its parent element?

It's hard to accurately display my code because I'm trying to modify Kibana and there are many different files involved but here is my best attempt at a simplified example:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr class="headerRow">
                <th>...</th>
                ...
            </tr>
            <tr class="headerRowInvisible">
                <th>...</th>
                ...
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>...</tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    z-index: auto;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 26px;
    position: relative;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.headerRow {
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 50;
}
.headerRowInvisible {
    white-space: nowrap;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

If you're wondering about the invisible `<tr>`, setting the position to absolute messed with the formatting of the rest of the table and overlapped with the top of it, so I created an invisible `<tr>` with normal positioning so that it would create space and provide correct column widths to the table body. The background and z-index is so that the sticky header will properly cover the body when you scroll down. Otherwise you get text on top of text and it looks jumbled.

Comment: Hi! You may try to wrap the table in a 100% width div.

Comment: Tried adding that to the parent div but unfortunately it did nothing. I did update the question with the CSS of the div container, though.

Comment: What happens if you give that div a set width and the overflow to hidden?

Comment: Width doesn't help but setting the overflow did! Sadly it is still covering the scrollbar, but at least it is no longer overflowing, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `top`, `right` and `left` properties to adjust the placement of that absolutely positioned element, and use `margin-top` on the next non-absolutely positioned element below it to create some space in order to avoid overlapping.

Comment: For some reason, ```margin-top``` didn't work, which is what led to my hacky invisible element. Regardless, the position of the element is fine, it is the overflow that I want to get rid of.

Comment: You could also try a `padding-top` on the table itself

Comment: And another approach would be to set a `margin-top` for the table (for example 50px) and use the same value, but negative(i.e. `top: -50px` in my example) for the `top` parameter of the absolutely positioned header to move it *above*  the actual table into the space created by the `margin-top`.